# Order of execution of startup(boot) programs and "after time"

Tags: command-line, boot, batch

Is there a way to make custom startup programs to run after "some time" after boot up..
How to sort(order of execution) programs "specific amount of time(after another program)" ?
Maybe a batch file, but which command ?
For example: 
"run this,(after 3min) run that"
Via batch or.. ?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: sounds like Windows to me :\

Answer (score 2):

With [Soluto](http://www.soluto.com/) you can delay some startup programs. And get rid of unnecessary ones...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in one batch file for your custom programs. Have it start up with task scheduler and call this batch file when you want to pause:

```
@ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 -w 1000 > nul
@ping 127.0.0.1 -n %1% -w 1000> nul
```

e.g.:

```
@echo off
start notepad
call wait.bat 30
start calc
call wait.bat 15
```

wait.bat is the batch file containing the ping code above. When invoked in the script as shown above, the argument is the wait time in seconds that your script will pause for. Ensure it is accessible via the same directory or PATH environment variable before trying to call it.

Comment: I entered the "wait.bat" location to PATH environment, but when i try to call the 2nd batch, it acts like that "wait.bat" doesn't exist..
I entered location of "wait.bat" with name "wait" and 2nd variable name "wait.bat"

Comment: Try putting the batch script into the same directory as the other script?

Comment: You might also wish to try `sleep 60` (or your desired time delay, in seconds) instead of using the ping delay method. I'm on Win XP SP3 here at work and have `sleep` available, I think earlier versions of XP didn't have it. I'd imagine it's also probably available on newer versions of Windows.

Comment: If you wan't sleep.exe you need to download it from the Server 2003 resource kit. Newer versions of windows have waitfor and timeout commands.